# How to export the matches only in a pattern search in vim?

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

Is there a way to grab and export the match part only in a pattern search without changing the current file?

For example, from a file containing:

```
57","0","37","","http://www.thisamericanlife.org/Radio_Episode.aspx?episode=175"
58","0","37","","http://www.thisamericanlife.org/Radio_Episode.aspx?episode=170"
```

I want to export a new file containing:

```
http://www.thisamericanlife.org/Radio_Episode.aspx?episode=175
http://www.thisamericanlife.org/Radio_Episode.aspx?episode=170
```

I can do this by using substitution like this:

```
:s/.\{-}\(http:\/\/.\{-}\)".\{-}/\1/g
:%w>>data
```

But the substitution command changes the current file. Is there a way to do this without changing the current file?

**Update:**

I am looking for a command like this:

```
:g/pattern/.w>>newfile
```

This command write the whole line where match occurs. I want to export only the match, not the whole line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your order:

```
 :w newfile.txt
 :e newfile.txt
 :%s/.\{-}\(http:\/\/.\{-}\)".\{-}/\1/g
 :w
```

Answer (score 2):

```
redir >>newfile
g/^/let g:match=matchstr(getline(line('.')), pattern) | if g:match!=#"" | silent echo g:match | endif
redir END
```

Explanation:

`redir >> newfile`

Start redirecting messages to file `newfile`, append if it exists.

`g/^/`

For each line

`getline(line('.'))`

get line contents

`let g:match(getline(line('.')), pattern)`

find a part of the line which matches `pattern` and save it in `g:match` variable

`if g:match!=#""`

if line matched pattern

`echo g:match`

output matched line

`silent echo g:match`

but only to the location specified by the `redir` command.

`redir END`

Stop redirecting output.

Comment: Wow, that's great but a little difficult. Thank you for the detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
:e currfile.txt
:s/.\{-}\(http:\/\/.\{-}\)".\{-}/\1/g
:w newfile.txt
```

Or would you like to continue editing the previous file?

**EDIT:** Or you could simply undo (press 'u').

Comment: Yes, this is similar to what I do. I can undo but I wonder if there is a way to do it without changing current file like :g/pattern/.w>>newfile